# PHP from commandline starts gui programs but apache doesn't

Tags: php, linux, apache

First, I read some threads by people with similar problems but all answers didn't go beyond export DISPLAY=:0.0 and xauth cookies. So here is my problem and thanks in advance for your time!

I have developed a little library which renders shelves using OpenGL and GLSL.
Last few days I wrapped it in a php extension and surprisingly easy it works now.

But the problem is it works only when I execute the php script using the extension from commandline 
`$php r100.php`(i successfuly run this from the http user). The script is in the webroot of apache and if I request it from the browser I get `** CRITICAL **: Unable to open display` in apache's error_log.

So, to make things easier to test and to be sure that the problem is not in the library/extension, at the moment I just want to start xmms with following php script.
`<?php
echo shell_exec("xmms");
?>`
It works only from the shell too.

I've played with apache configuration so much now that I really dont know what to try.
I tried `$xhost + && export DISPLAY=:0.0`

In the http.conf I have these 
`SetEnv DISPLAY :0.0` `SetEnv XAUTHORITY /home/OpenGL/.Xauthority`

So my problem seems to be this:
**How can I make apache execute php script with all privileges that the http user has, including the environment?**

Additional information:
*HTTP* is in video and users groups and has a login shell(bash).
I can login as http and execute scripts with no problem and can run GUI programs which show up on display 0.
It seems that apache does not provide the appropriate environment for the script.
I read about some difference between CLI/CGI but cant run xmms with php-cgi too...

Any ideas for additional configuration?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds bit hazard, but basically you can add even export DISPLAY=:0.0 to apache start-up script (like in Linux /etc/init.d/httpd or apache depending distro).
And "xhost +" need to be run on account which is connected to local X server as user, though I'm only wondering how it will work as php script should only live while apache http request is on-going.

Edit:
Is this is kind of application launcher?, you can spawn this with exec("nohub /usr/bin/php script.php &"); .. now apache should be released and php should continue working in background.

Comment: this was the real answer, actually I added export DISPLAY=:0 to /etc/environment. The xauth is just security issue and I am going to play with it but the env var was my problem :)

Comment: to your last question, no it is not app launcher, in the extension I call functions from the library I developed.

Comment: @NaydenDochev I just try to figure how you manage to run those, as usually any php (with apache) function is only living while request is on-going. Of course one way is launch to background and store pid to somewhere for "kill" command. Or does extensions live while apache is running? Anyway, good that you found solution :)

Comment: Hi, if you look at the zend extension guides, it will be easier to clarify but no, extensions dont live with apache, but anything can be stored in the session anyways. The way I use the library, has nothing to do with realtime desktop apps, its just single-pass drawing according to the size and materials. I made it a php extension instead of command-line tool(much simpler and more clean approach) just because this is what I was asked to do :)

Answer (score 1):

In your console, allow everyone to use the X server:

```
xhost +
```

In your PHP script, set the DISPLAY variable while executing the commands:

```
DISPLAY=:0 glxgears 2>&1
```

Comment: Do not do `xhost +`. It is totally insecure. Take a look here: http://www.lugod.org/pipermail/vox-tech/2005-March/010864.html

Comment: ok, this worked , now I need to think how to make this work also when using function from the extension. Thank you!

Comment: @ceving, my X11 doesn't seem to listen on any interface, even after `xhost +`. What would you suggest instead of `xhost +` ?

Comment: @arnaud576875 You have to enable TCP if you want your X server to listen on a port. See here: http://www.unixtutorial.org/2007/08/allow-incoming-tcp-connections-x11-redhat-rhel4/