# How to fork a new process on my OS, using PHP

Tags: php, vlc

Goal: To launch VLC player through PHP code, and play the specified video in the player. 
OS: Ubuntu 11.10

Problem: Please refer my script below (still new to PHP), I see no video playing, and not even a background VLC process running on executing this script. Can you please point out the issue and appropriate documentation that will help me make this work? If I issue the same command on shell, the video plays, but on using "system" command of PHP, no video plays.

Script:

```
<?php
system('/usr/bin/vlc /home/atish/Videos/TEDGary.avi', $retval);
echo $retval;
?>
```

Output on the webpage:

```
0
```

Bigger goal: I want provide a webinterface for the user to run my application (C-code). My c-code application that implements some video transcoding and management workflows, I want to be able to run that C code in background, and when it finishes, I want to play the video in VLC.

Thankyou.

Comment: Where do you want the vlc player to start? On the server? On the client? Are client and server always the same machine?

Comment: yes, the client and server are same machine. I am just wanting to have a web interface for my app in a way. I want the video to start on the same machine as where the php script is being executed...

Comment: The first question that arises is: does the user the web server run as have priviledges to open windows in your user's current desktop?

Comment: Any pointers on how I can grant such permissions/privileges to the web server user? Thanks

Comment: Thank you, xhost +localhost seems to be the way to grant such privileges. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow everyone to use the X server:

```
xhost +
```

In your script, set the DISPLAY variable when executing the command:

```
system('DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/vlc /home/atish/Videos/TEDGary.avi', $retval);
```

However, I'd also recommend you to consider the security implications when using xhost.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to provide some OS info (Linux? Mac?), and possibly some info about your window manager. Playing the video in VLC may be somewhat more difficult than just launching the background process, which is explained here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Getting a gui app up and running can be tricky, but play with "xhost" and exporting your DISPLAY config - see [PHP from commandline starts gui programs but apache doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301396/php-from-commandline-starts-gui-programs-but-apache-doesnt)

Comment: Thank you, the second link helped. I am able to see vlc pop up now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<?php
exec('nohup /usr/bin/vlc /home/atish/Videos/TEDGary.avi &');
?>
```

The & at the end tells the process to run in the background and the nohup at the front tells the process not to get killed when the launching shell (in this case php) is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need PHP to be able to use your user account (login as you) to be able to open a graphical window. PHP generally uses apache's user and not your own user. I do not know if you can have 2 processes using one user account. Try using the SU command or some other command.